# click dynamic highchart to open in new window

Tags: popup, highcharts, highslide

I need help in opening the highchart in a popup while clciking the chart

```
$(document).ready(DrawMyGraph1);


  function DrawMyGraph1() {
   var   xaxis = $.parseJSON($("#hdnXaxis").val());
   var   series1 = $.parseJSON($("#hdnYaxis").val());

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
    {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'container3',
            defaultSeriesType: 'area',
            events: {
                click: function () 
                {

                }
            }

        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: xaxis,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'No of Patients'
            }
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.series.name + ' - ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
            }
        },
        series: series1
    });

}
```

I need to call the function  "hs.Expander.prototype" in the chart click event to open the highchart in a popup using highslide .Can anyone help

Comment: Take a look: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax It's almost the same you want - the only difference is that events are binded to points, and you want bind to the chart.

Answer (score 1):

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/eteqX/
It’s important to call the Highslide files in the head section of the page - before the code for the chart.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://highcharts.com/highslide/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.config.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css"/>
```